# How can I get only one row if only one column is different

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with patient ID's, contact dates and actioncodes. I want to retrieve all rows with actioncodes equal to EPS or D, however i want to keep only one row if the actioncode exists on the same contactdate.

For example this is part of my table, journal:

```
PatientID  Contactdate  Actioncode
1          2010-5-6     EPS
1          2010-5-6     D
1          2012-3-4     CNT
1          2013-7-8     D
2          2010-1-4     EPS
2          2010-5-6     D
```

This is the code i have now to retrieve all rows where actioncode is either EPS or D

```
select * from journal j where j.actioncode in ('EPS', 'D')
```

I tried group by contactdate, but then i miss the rows where the patients are different. The same effect occurs with distinct(contactdate). What can i use here to return only one row when the date and the patientid are similar and the actioncode is either D or EPS?

Preferred outcome:

```
PatientID   Contactd   Actioncode
1           2010-5-6   D
1           2012-3-4   D
2           2010-1-4   EPS
2           2010-5-6   D
```

Comment: And which row do you want to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a `GROUP BY` two columns: PatientID and Contactdate. You can use `MAX()` or `MIN()` to select one of the rows.

```
select
j.PatientID,
j.Contactdate,
MIN(j.actionCode)
from 
journal j 
where j.actioncode in ('EPS', 'D')
group by j.PatientID, j.Contactdate
```

For match your preferred outcome, you should use `MIN()`.

Answer (score 2):

We can try using `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PatientID, Contactdate
                                 ORDER BY Actioncode) rn
    FROM journal
    WHERE Actioncode in ('EPS', 'D')
)

SELECT PatientID, Contactdate, Actioncode
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

This arbitrarily would always retain the `Actioncode='D'` record, should both action codes appear.  If instead you would want to retain the `EPS` record, then modify the call to `ROW_NUMBER` to use `ORDER BY Actioncode DESC`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with UNION ALL for the 2 cases:

```
select * from journal where actioncode = 'D'
union all
select * from journal j where j.actioncode = 'EPS'
and not exists (
  select 1 from journal
  where PatientID = j.PatientID and Contactdate = j.Contactdate and actioncode = 'D'
)
```

The 2nd query will only fetch rows if the 1st query returns nothing for `actioncode = 'D'`.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=ea6ec152e607c47ae5934f66100f7362).
Results:

```
> patientid | contactdate | actioncode
> --------: | :---------- | :---------
>         1 | 2010-05-06  | D         
>         1 | 2013-07-08  | D         
>         2 | 2010-05-06  | D         
>         2 | 2010-01-04  | EPS
```